# Auto fade out and fade In on hover animation

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, fadein, fadeout

## This is auto fade out after hover css animation

I'm trying to show a notification on video play button. The button click actually clicked for video play. I want to show a div with its content with the play icon. However, I would like to fade out the play icon, lets say after 5 seconds . I would like to achieve it using CSS. Below is my attempt. Please inform me if better solution here.

### Here is the live [Demo](https://codepen.io/mrana/pen/NWPamGL)

```css
body {
  font-size: 50%;
  font-style: Arial;
}

.animation-box {
  width: 75%;
  height: 27.5rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.animation-container {
  width: 1000rem;
  height: 30rem;
}

.first-text {
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2.5rem;
  top: 5rem;
  color: white;
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 2s forwards;
    animation: fadeOut 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
}

.first-text:hover {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0s forwards;
    animation: fadeIn 0s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<section class="animation-box">
    <h1 class="first-text">This is auto fade out after hover </h1>
  </section>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Jquery` ?

Comment: try animate.css & jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.Class {
    transition: all 0.5s;
color: #ff0;
margin: 50px;
font-size: 28px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.Class:hover {
    color: #00f;
}
```

```html
<p class="Class"> This is me </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with just `transition` :

```css
body {
  font-size: 50%;
  font-style: Arial;
}

.animation-box {
  width: 75%;
  height: 27.5rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
h1{
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 250ms 5s ease;
}

.animation-box:hover h1{
  opacity:1;
  transition-delay: 250ms;
}
```

```html
<section class="animation-box">
    <h1 class="first-text">This is auto fade ou1t after hover </h1>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **transition:0.5s ease** with **opacity:0**

```
<section class="animation-box">
<h1 class="first-text">This is auto fade ou1t after hover </h1>
</section>

.animation-box{
transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.animation-box:hover{
opacity:0;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```